# Project Euler 642

Tags: python, primes

Here's the problem:

> Let f(n) be the largest prime factor of n and F(n) = sum(f(i) for i in range(2, n+1)).
>
> For example F(10)=32, F(100)=1915 and F(10000)=10118280.
>
> Find F(201820182018). Give your answer modulus 10**9.

I know how to do this in principle (in Python) and get answers for smaller numbers w/o a problem. I learned a lot in struggling with this. Case Van Horsen's gmpy2 method of generating the primes needed was incredibly fast for huge numbers but just would not work for the 201820182018 number. I've come to the conclusion that the number is just too big for my 8gig MacBookPro or my WindowsPC 16 gig machine. The 16 gig PC does not have the memory to use Carl Sweigart's implementation of the Eratosthenes sieve.
I could probably solve it if I had access to a computer with much, much more memory but I am wondering if I am missing something in the approach.

Comment: I edited the Project Euler description to match Python's syntax and to be more readable in the StackExchange web page. Roll the edit back if you do not like it. Second, please show your code for "answers for smaller numbers w/o a problem." Finally, you really should not ask for help with Project Euler problems--the directors of that site [explicitly state this](https://projecteuler.net/about), and you will learn more and enjoy more by doing the problem on your own.

Comment: I asked a question on Tapatalk - there was a hint provided and I did not understand the math in the hint.  Still waiting on the answer there - but it's probably more math than I could easily follow.